# Why are these two DIVs displayed over each other?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

The following code blends both DIVs together instead of displaying them vertically, one after another. Both are set to `display: block` and I'd like to know which style attribute makes them behave like this?! See [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cw86p/2/).

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div  data-role="content">
        <div>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" style="float: left">Do something</a>

            <span href="#" style="float: right; border-radius: 10px; background-color: white; padding: .6em">Something</span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#">Foo list entry</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using the floating elements you have to close them with element containing **clear:both** style, so the part of the code will be:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" style="float: left">Do something</a>

    <span href="#" style="float: right; border-radius: 10px; background-color: white; padding: .6em">Something</span>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the working JSFiddle (with a little bit of margin modification as well): http://jsfiddle.net/Cw86p/9/

Comment: or give them height attribute

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks. Finally learned about floating :)